# how to apply custom schema to pyspark dataframe having more than 38 columns

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, types

For example,

In my dataframe 30 columns are integer datatype and rest are strings. Is there any efficient way to define the schema rather than writting one column name one by one.

Thank you in advance.

I can do with tradition way like
schema_str= """
`a` Integer,
`b` string,
`c` String,
`d` Integer
"""

but not feel like good idea having 40 columns

Comment: what happens if you let spark infer the schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture the two different column types in two arrays.

In each array, store the names of the columns of that type.

```
val integerCols = df.schema.fields.filter(dataType==IntegerType).map(_.name)
val stringCols = df.schema.fields.filter(dataType==StringType).map(_.name)
```

Then, simply create strings from the arrays...

```
integerCols.map(_ + " Integer").mkString(", ") + ", " + 
 stringCols.map(_ + " String").mkString(", ")
```